# Alarm not being fired on Gear emulator

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

I am trying to create a Tizen app to be invoked from wearable webapp that fires an alarm at a certain time but it is never fired.

I've added these to the `config.xml`:

```xml
<feature name="http://tizen.org/api/tizen" required="true"/>
<feature name="http://tizen.org/api/alarm" required="true"/>
<feature name="http://tizen.org/api/alarm.read" required="true"/>
<feature name="http://tizen.org/api/alarm.write" required="true"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/application.launch"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/alarm"/>
```

And the following code in `.js` file:

```js
var alarm = new tizen.AlarmRelative(30);
tizen.alarm.add(alarm, "org.tizen.clock");
console.log("Alarm added with id: " + alarm.id);
```

When run, I get a correct id but the clock (or other apps) are never shown. The same happens when I try to schedule an `AlarmAbsolute`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Got same issue. Not working even with current appInfo.id, tizen.internet, org.tizen.browser. tizen.alarm.getAll().length is always 0.

Answer (score 0):

In example looks like is problem with **AplicatonId** ('org.tizen.clock') - the second parameter for alarm.add function. Looks like emulator cannot find this application. 
I tested the same function with my application. This is working correctly on emulator. 
You can use your application id. Your application id is located in configuration file (**config.xml**) on **tab Tizen** or in xml node **tizen:application**.